# How can an error exist in a pipeline build but not an IDE build?

Tags: git, vb.net, forms, pipeline

I have a git pipeline running a build for a set of projects. One of these projects is having an issue with a reference to one form within another. The way the two forms works is the first is a list of commands and the second is an edit form for those commands. The edit form is showing "Error BC30002: Type 'frmEdit' is not defined". This error does not show up in compile of the project, only the pipeline; I have no idea how to fix an error that doesn't exist.

Comment: I ran into a problem with msbuild's logic for deciding build order; even with a dependency specifically set in the solution, msbuild would still decide that it could build them in the opposite order, and much hilarity ensued.  I was only able to fix this by using the "/graphbuild:True" option.  You might want to check and see if you're having a build order problem, if so, you can try explicitly setting a build dependency, and if that doesn't work, you can try a graph build.

Comment: I'm not sure how build order would cause this issue but I'll check. Though I don't think that's the case because the list form has multiple edit forms it calls to depending on the type of command and which button the user clicks. Out of all three of them, only the most recently added is having the error.